# How do I get an autoincremented primary key from mysql using c#?

Tags: c#, mysql

I want to create an event than immediately register the user who created that event in an events attendance table.  No field for the event is unique, except the primary key and this is assigned by the database.  Is there anyway to get a row number or specific field from the last row affected by a non-query on an active database connection?

Comment: Are you using EntityFramework or ADO.NET?

Comment: You can add your code snippet to get attention from others.

Comment: You might want to look into MySql's LAST_INSERT_ID() function.

Answer (score 1):

If you insert a record into a table that contains an AUTO_INCREMENT column, you can obtain the value stored into that column by calling the `mysql_insert_id()` function.

See the MySQL documentation for more info: [28.6.28.3 How to Get the Unique ID for the Last Inserted Row](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/getting-unique-id.html)